# hcatalog with mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hcatalog

I get the following error while executing a MapReduce program.
I have placed all jars in hadoop/lib directory and have also mentioned the jars in -libjars.

This is the cmd I am executing:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop --config $HADOOP_HOME/conf jar /home/shash/distinct.jar  HwordCount -libjars $LIB_JARS WordCount HWordCount2

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat at 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:996) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getOutputFormatClass(JobContext.java:248) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.initialize(Task.java:501) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:306) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415) at 
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127) at 
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.HCatOutputFormat 
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at 
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) at 
org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:943) 
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:994) ... 
8 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure LIB_JARS is a comma-separated list (as opposed to colon-separated like CLASSPATH)

Answer (score 0):

> Applies To    CDH 5.0.x CDH 5.1.x CDH 5.2.x CDH 5.3.x Sqoop
>
> Cause  Sqoop cannot pick up the HCatalog libraries because Cloudera
>   Manager does not set the HIVE_HOME environment. It needs to be set
>   manually.

This problem is tracked with below JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2145

The fix of this JIRA has been included in CDH since version 5.4.0.

Workaround: Applicable to CDH versions lower than 5.4.0.

Execute below commands in shell before calling Sqoop command or adding them to /etc/sqoop/conf/sqoop-env.sh (create one, if it does not already exists):

```
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/hive   (for parcel installation)
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive (for package installation)
```